# Returning pointers to string literals in c

Tags: c, pointers, string-literals

This is a trivial program where I want to take in a string literal and return a pointer to a string literal. I understand that string literals are constant so this can't be done. So what is the right way of doing this.
This program prints the same string that was passed in.

```
char* sort(char* str){
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < len -1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; ++j)
        {
            if (str[j]<str[i])
            {
                swap(str[j], str[i]);

            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return str;
}//end of sort
```

Also if you suggest a malloc, where do I free the heap.

Comment: @Subinoy: I think OP is passing in a string literal so it can't be modified.

Comment: A string like this ? : str[] = "string literal"

Comment: I think he means `char *str = "string literal";` or `sort("string literal");`

Comment: Your function can't be used with a string literal, because it modifies it. It needs to make a copy before it sorts it. The caller will need to free it.

Comment: you need to copy first, have a look at `strdup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in a pointer to the array where to store the result. That way, all your memory management can be handled outside the function.

```
void sort(const char* const strLit, size_t strLitSize, char *strSorted, size_t strSortedSize) {
    memcpy(strSorted, strLit, strLitSize);
    int len = strlen(strLit);
    for (int i = 0; i < len -1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; ++j)
        {
            if (strSorted[j]<strSorted[i])
            {
                swap(strSorted[j], strSorted[i]);

            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
}//end of sort
```

You can call it like this:

```
#define str "some string here";
size_t sizeSorted = strlen(str) * sizeof(char);
char *pSorted = malloc( sizeSorted );

sort(str, sizeof(str), pSorted, sizeSorted);

printf("%s\n", pSorted);
free(pSorted);
```

Better yet, just make a copy outside and use your function as is.

Comment: for string, it isn't quite worth it for all this work. `strdup` is created for duplicating string, so there is no need to reinvent that. perfect for any other data types though.

Comment: @rost0031 is `char str[]` the string literal here?

Comment: it's not. `str` is modifiable.

Comment: Can you tell me which one is the string literal? I am not getting this.

Comment: string literal should be pointed by pointer, if you delare `str` as `char *`, that would do.

Comment: Can you check the https://ideone.com/lntBfw code here and can you tell me is this is an example of string literal or not, Please @HuStmpHrrr

Comment: @Subinoy it's not. string literal shall be pointed by a pointer. you seem to be confused by pointers and arrays.

Comment: I made str a define so it's actually a string literal.  Sorry, it was technically not a string literal but I specifically made the arguments const char* const so that the function was guaranteed not to modify it.

Comment: i doubt your code won't compile. `strLit` now is a `const char *`, this pointer cannot be used to modify the content.

Comment: It's not being modified.

Comment: i think it tend to be. `swap` should be an inplace modification function. op just feels lazy to write that completely or it's a macro. otherwise, the whole function doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: Yes, swap is acting on strSorted, not strLit.

Comment: I got it, I understood it by `const char *`, @HuStmpHrrr

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a decision about whether this function will modify the supplied string in-place, or allocate a new string. You cannot modify a string literal in-place because, as you pointed out, it is constant.

### Option 1: modify in-place

This is pretty much what you've got, but if the caller wants to use a string literal they will need to do something like:

```
char *s = strdup("hello");
sort(s);
// use s here
free(s);
```

### Option 2: allocate a new string

Alternatively, you can do the allocation in your sort function:

```
char* sort(char *input){
    int len = strlen(input);
    char *str = strdup(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < len -1; ++i)
    /// etc.
```

The caller will then be responsible for calling `free` on the result once they're done with it.

```
char *s = sort("hello");
// use s here
free(s);
```

Either way, the caller is responsible for freeing the newly allocated string.